# "Show/Hide" menu items in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, menu

I'm developing an app in Android Studio, and what i am most struggling about is the menu. I didn't want to use master detail flow, neither overflow menu. I ended up using a ListView, and each item of the list is an option from the menu. Now, one thing i wanted to do is when i click some item of the menu it shows another menu, a submenu, with other options, and when i click again on the first item then the submenu becomes not visible. And another thing i have no idea how to do regarding that, is when i open the submenu, the other items of the list have to change position, so that the submenu items don't stand on top of the other items, and when i close everything comes again to the initial form.
I hope you guys understood my problem, can you help me ? :)

I haven't done much yet, this is just the format of the menu, created with ListViews. And now i wanted like to one of the items, for example "Horarios" to expand and show other items when i click on it, instead of creating a new intent like i did with "Contatos"

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String[] menu = {"Horarios", "Tarifas", "Trajetos", "Hiperligacoes", "Contatos"};
    ListAdapter moisesAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, menu);
    ListView moisesListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.moisesListView);
    moisesListView.setAdapter(moisesAdapter);

    moisesListView.setOnItemClickListener(
            new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    String menu = String.valueOf(parent.getItemIdAtPosition(position));
                    switch (menu){
                        case "4":
                            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Contatos.class);
                            MainActivity.this.startActivity(i);

                    }
                }
            }
    );
}
```

Comment: Could you [give more details](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) please? Maybe include some code you wrote and which is not working, some screenshots.

Comment: I edit the post.. Has i said above i haven't done much yet, just created the  menu, with ListViews. And now i wanted like to one of the items, for example "Horarios" to expand and show other items when i click on it, instead of creating a new intent like i did with "Contatos"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't realize, but what i wanted is exactlu what expandable listview exists for. I didn't know the existence of that, i'm kind new at android develpment.